# Full automorphism group of a Bruhat-Tits building

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, algebraic-groups, buildings

If we start with a semisimple algebraic group $G$ defined over a non-archimedean local field and want to understand the relationship of this group with the full type-preserving automorphism group of the associated Bruhat-Tits building, is there any reference in the literature which would help me get a better handle on that? Specifically I'm interested in any sufficient conditions for when it's an open subgroup, if that does indeed ever occur.

Comment: I guess you mean the Euclidean building, on which $G_k$ acts properly cocompactly. In finite characteristic it's never an open subgroup. The reason is that the automorphism group $K$ of the underlying topological group sits in the isometry group, and has finite intersection with the action of the (group of points of the) algebraic group. In characteristic zero if $G$ has no rank $1$ factor it's an open subgroup, I think it follows from results of Tits (which also provide a full description in finite char.).

Comment: By the way in finite characteristic, it's an open question whether there exists $G$ (centerfree, with no rank 1 factor) such that some lattice in $\mathrm{Isom}(X_G)$ doesn't meet $G$ in a lattice, $X_G$ being the Euclidean building.